# Link on Link - How to activate JS code without parent link activation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a case:

```
<a href="#1" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
  <div class="#2"></div>
  <div class="#3"></div>
  <div class="#4"></div>
  <div>
    <input onclick="#5" />
  </div>
</a>
```

By default, if I click on #2,#3,#4,#5 I will be redirected to #1.

So how I have to fix CSS if I want to click on the input without #1 activation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's you javascript and css code? You forgot to post those. Not really sure what you're asking here...

Comment: `<input onclick="#5" />` - life keeps surprising me. What's that supposed to be?

Comment: OK, let's suggest that 
<input onclick="addtocart();" />

When I click on the input JS-code runs and simultaneously I'm redirected to #1. 
So I want to ignore #1 when I click on the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can do it like this:

```
<a href="#1" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
  <div class="#2"></div>
  <div class="#3"></div>
  <div class="#4"></div>
  <div>
    <input onclick="doSomething(); return false;" />
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a

```
return(false);
```

at the end of the JavaScript that is executed when clicking the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your  tag is written correctly, use z-index:

```
 <input type="button" style="z-index:99" onclick="foo()" />
```

Though I wonder if you should rethink your page layout and avoid such a large link tag...

Comment: There is just a small thumbnail from Bootstrap :)
So I want to avoid img links, name links etc.
Just one link to support the SEO policy

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem that I faced several times.

You basically need to listen for the click event on the parent element, then check if it's an anchor or other element and then act upon it.

```
$('YOUR ELEMENT').click(function (e) {
  var target = $( e.target );
  if ( target.is( "a" ) ) {

    Do something
  }
  else if (target.is( "input" ))
  {
    Do something else

  }
});
```

Although I wouldn't recommend having an anchor as a wrapper to div as it breaks in some cases, with this approach you can easily use a wrapper div with a data-link attribute and navigate to this link programmatically through JavaScript